# Printing the last field on the last line

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, grep

So there's an application that tells me what's my current IP. Instead of just printing the IP, the output is:

```
Starting GetIP process...
Getting your IP...
Your current IP: 127.0.0.1
```

Is there a way to just save the IP to a file? Either by removing first 2 lines and beginning of the third, or by just saving the actual numbers and dots.

I know I can trim down the first two lines with `sed` but how do I remove the text on the third line? (By the way, expected output is just the IP, no colons or whitespaces).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this easily with `awk`:

```
$ your_command | awk 'END{print $NF}' 
127.0.0.1
```

To store to a file use the redirection operator:

```
$ your_command | awk 'END{print $NF}' > my_ip
```

In `awk` the `END` block is executed after the input has been read so we are looking at the last line in the input. `NF` is a special `awk` variable that contains the number of fields on the current line *(so 4 in this case)* where the default field separator is whitespace. The `$` means print the field value i.e. `{print $1}` prints the first field value `$2` the second ect.

---

One way with `sed`:

```
$ your_command | sed -n '3s/.*: //p' 
127.0.0.1

# save to file
$ your_command | sed -n '3s/.*: //p' > my_ip
```

The option `-n` turns off the defaulting printing of every line. The `3` is address *(the line number)* of the line we want to operate on. We want to perform a substitution *(the s command)* for everything `.*` upto the colon followed by a space `:` and replace it with an empty string. The forward slashes are the chosen delimiters and the `p` is the print command so only the third line is printed after the substitution has taken place.

---

Using `grep` and the `-o` option you can print all matches of a given IP matching regular expression:

```
$ your_command | egrep -o '([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}$'

# save to file
$ your_command | egrep -o '([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}$' > my_ip
```

---

The best solution on Linux would be to use `hostname`:

```
$ hostname -I
127.0.0.1

# save to file
$ hostname -I > my_ip
```

This isn't portable however as the `-I` option is available with the OSX version of the `hostname` command.

Comment: I'd use `END{print $NF}` if it works for you but it's worth mentioning that not all awks retain the last records values ($0, $NF, etc.) in the END section so then you might need `{s=$NF}END{print s}`.